# Multiple Login endpoints Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to implement multiple login strategies for different user roles (Spring Security OAuth2 with Spring Boot 2), and each strategy should use a different endpoint. I have 3 user types, `REGULAR, EXTERNAL, CLIENT`, where regular logs in vía username/password, external logs in via documentId/key, and client does some SMS shenanigans before to acquire the current password, and it logs with phone/password. They can already log in from a regular website, but they'll have mobile applications for each role.

I've tried to create multiple `AuthorizationServer` instances with `@EnableAuthorizationServer`, each one with the config, but it only picks up the last one. Each role has a different `UserDetailsService` impl, and exactly one app created in the DB. I wanted to expose them so that client apps use `/client/oauth/...`, regular apps use `/regular/oauth/...` and external apps use `/external/oauth/...` How can I achieve this?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: I ended up separating it into microservices, so this part of the backend was dealt with a custom service in another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the spring security and oauth2 and you want to get many different login endpoint you may need to custom **AuthenticationEntryPoint**.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String clientId = request.getParameter("client_id");
        String redirectUrl = "/login";
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute(SessionSaveAttribute.CLIENT_ID_ATR, clientId);
        //echoSessionAtr(request);
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
    }

}
```

So you may can can custom the login endpoint by make your condition.

```
if(clientId=="REGULAR_CLIENT_ID"){
    redirectUrl = "regular/login"
} else if(clientId=="SPECIAL_CLIENT_ID"){
    redirctUrl = "...";
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what actually happens here? I have the same requirement as OP but I don't quite see what your code does exactly.

Comment: Again, because this requirement needs to show different login page base on client id right? if yes, we can redirect url here: redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);

Comment: +1 a hint in the right direction for me - I was pulling out my hair to find a way to bypass the default OAuth2 Spring Security "choose your provider" default login screen and apparently this works

Comment: Glade to heard it helpful for you. @hello_earth